# List of hex colors work with pie but not plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I try to create a color theme to be used with matplotlib and it works fine with pie charts but I get an error message saying that it is an invalid RGBA argument when running `plt.plot(x,y,color = color_theme)`

Works

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
color_theme = ['#998166', '#bacfd9', '#bfbaa6', '#a0bab8', '#63605b', 
'#8f8a83', '#bdb6af', '#e8e5e3', '#634632']
x = list(range(1,10))
y = [1,2,3,4,.5,4,3,2,1]
plt.pie(x, colors = color_theme)
```

Do not work

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
color_theme = ['#998166', '#bacfd9', '#bfbaa6', '#a0bab8', '#63605b', 
'#8f8a83', '#bdb6af', '#e8e5e3', '#634632']
x = list(range(1,10))
y = [1,2,3,4,.5,4,3,2,1]
plt.plot(x,y,color = color_theme)
```

Leaving out the `color` argument works as well.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `plt.plot` plots a line. You only have 1 line in the plot, therefore you can only give one value in the `color=` argument (you can have a line with multiple colors, there are other questions on SO about that).

You can choose one element of your `color_theme` list and choose that

```
plt.plot(x,y,color = color_theme[0]) # uses '#998166' for the color.
```

You might want to use a scatter plot which can accept a list of colors:

```
color_theme = ['#998166', '#bacfd9', '#bfbaa6', '#a0bab8', '#63605b',
'#8f8a83', '#bdb6af', '#e8e5e3', '#634632']
x = list(range(1,10))
y = [1,2,3,4,.5,4,3,2,1]
plt.scatter(x, y, color = color_theme)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I thought that it worked like the `cycler` in mplstyle, but I see that it didn't. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcusHögenåBohman: If you strictly have to use the second method, you can use a for loop but that would be too verbose.